# What is wrong with the following Clojure program ? Memoized version of Fibonacci

Tags: clojure

```
(def fibVal {1 1 2 1})

(defn fibonacci [x]               
  (if (false? (get fibVal x false)) 
    (do
      (println (str "Evaluating " x))
      (def fibVal (assoc fibVal x (+ (fibonacci(- x 1)) (fibonacci(- x 2)))))
      (println (str x " Evaluated to " (fibVal x)))
      (fibVal x)                                
    )
    (get fibVal x)
  )
)
```

Output for (fibonacci 5)
Evaluating 5
Evaluating 4
Evaluating 3
3 Evaluated to 2
4 Evaluated to 3
Evaluating 3
3 Evaluated to 2
5 Evaluated to 5
5
3 is evaluated twice whereas in the memoized version, it should be evaluted only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your program is the form:

```
(def fibVal (assoc fibVal
                x (+ (fibonacci (- x 1)) 
                     (fibonacci (- x 2)))))
```

The `fibVal` you are using in the first line is evaluated to its current value before the recursive calls write new versions of it. Whatever they do to the `fibVal` var will be forgotten when this `def` expression finally evaluates, because then it becomes the `fibVal` before they have been called with the sum of their return values associated into `x`.

---

`def` is intended vor top-level declaration, not for mutating global vars in recursive processes.

Also, your recursive implementation is not iterative, so it will blow the stack at a high enough n.

Here is an example of a stateful iterative implementation with memoization:

```
(def fib-cache (atom [0 1]))

(defn- calc-nth-fib
  [fibs n]
  (reduce (fn [fibs n]
            (assoc fibs n
                   (apply + (take 2 (rseq fibs)))))
          fibs
          (range (count fibs) (inc n))))

(defn fibonacci [x]
  (or (get @fib-cache x)
      (-> fib-cache
          (swap! calc-nth-fib x)
          (nth x))))
```

Note that this example does not represent the idiomatic way of finding the nth Fibonacci in Clojure as that requires one to generate the entire sequence up to the nth number on a single thread for which lazy-sequences are designed. They provide caching implicitly and are optimized for the desired usecase.

---

For an idiomatic Fibonacci implementation please refer to one of the many [lazy Fibonacci implementations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/Lazy_Fibonacci) and if necessary [learn about lazy sequences.](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/laziness.html)

Comment: Thank you :) This is my 3rd program in clojure, so I don't know much. 
Is it possible to update _fibVal_ in run-time by any means ? 
And I read that _do_ processes instructions in order, so why isn't it happening here ? I mean, even if def is not thread safe, it is being executed before returning the value.

Comment: You are correct. Thread safety is not a concern here. Note that `def` is a special form, so its evaluation rules and order are an undocumented implementation detail of the evaluator unlike with normal forms, so you shouldn't rely on it. However I found indeed that in this case the problem lies elsewhere and have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

using `def` in anything but a top level form is not thread safe and not guaranteed to work as you are using it. for storing state that changes like this you will most likely want to use one of the mutable state options such as atoms, refs, or agents.

In this case an atom would be a decent choice.